# Updating complex JSON object in Python

Tags: python, json, mongodb, python-3.x

I am grabbing sort of a complex MongoDB document with Python (v3.5) and I should update some values in it which are scattered all around the object and have no particular pattern in the structure and save it back to a different MongoDB collection. The object looks like this:

```
# after json.loads(mongo_db_document) my dict looks like this
notification = {
    '_id': '570f934f45213b0d14b1256f',
    'key': 'receipt',
    'label': 'Delivery Receipt',
    'version': '0.0.1',
    'active': True,
    'children': [
        {
            'key': 'started',
            'label': 'Started',
            'children': [
                'date',
                'time',
                'offset'
            ]
        },
        {
            'key': 'stop',
            'label': 'Ended',
            'children': [
                'date',
                'time',
                'offset'
            ]
        },
        {
            'label': '1. Particulars',
            'template': 'formGroup',
            'children': [
                {
                    'children': [
                        {
                            'key': 'name',
                            'label': '2.1 Name',
                            'value': '********** THIS SHOULD BE UPDATED **********',
                            'readonly': 'true'
                        },
                        {
                            'key': 'ims_id',
                            'label': '2.2 IMS Number',
                            'value': '********** THIS SHOULD BE UPDATED **********',
                            'readonly': 'true'
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    'children': [
                        {
                            'key': 'type',
                            'readonly': '********** THIS SHOULD BE UPDATED **********',
                            'label': '2.3 Type',
                            'options': [
                                {
                                    'label': 'Passenger',
                                    'value': 'A37'
                                },
                                {
                                    'label': 'Cargo',
                                    'value': 'A35'
                                },
                                {
                                    'label': 'Other',
                                    'value': '********** THIS SHOULD BE UPDATED **********'
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            'template': 'formGroup',
            'key': 'waste',
            'label': '3. Waste',
            'children': [
                {
                    'label': 'Waste',
                    'children': [
                        {
                            'label': 'Plastics',
                            'key': 'A',
                            'inputType': 'number',
                            'inputAttributes': {
                                'min': 0
                            },
                            'value': '********** THIS SHOULD BE UPDATED **********'
                        },
                        {
                            'label': 'B. Oil',
                            'key': 'B',
                            'inputType': 'number',
                            'inputAttributes': {
                                'min': 0
                            },
                            'value': '********** THIS SHOULD BE UPDATED **********'
                        },
                        {
                            'label': 'C. Operational',
                            'key': 'C',
                            'inputType': 'number',
                            'inputAttributes': {
                                'min': 0
                            },
                            'value': '********** THIS SHOULD BE UPDATED **********'
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            'template': 'formRow',
            'children': [
                'empty',
                'signature'
            ]
        }
    ],
    'filter': {
        'timestamp_of_record': [
            'date',
            'time',
            'offset'
        ]
    }
}
```

My initial idea was to put placeholders (like `$var_name`) in places where I need to update values, and load the string with Python's `string.Template`, but that approach unfortunately breaks lots of stuff to other users of the same MongoDB document for some reason.

Is there a solution to simply modify this kind of object without "hardcoding" path to find the values I need to update?

Comment: Are you asking how to find the paths to these values dynamically?

Comment: I get it that for some reason you can't load, modify and save as json again?

Comment: @C14L Well, yes, you can formulate my question in that way :) I can write a function which would go through whole dict and look for each and every possibility, but I was thinking if there is any simpler solution?

Comment: Can you give more details? Maybe an example case? It's impossible to come up with an answer for this kind of "hypothetical" question.

Comment: @Roberto Yeah, well, the same object is used in JavaScript, PostgreSQL and it is parsed in some other end, so putting placeholders like `$var_name` is at this moment very tricky.

Comment: @lesingerouge Well, my use case is that I have to pick up this document, update it and store it in a different MongoDB collection for later use. Simple as that.

Comment: @Roberto Eh, I misunderstood your question. I can load it, modify it and I have to save it as JSON back again. My problem is "modifying" part because there are no obvious placeholders or structure to each value I need to update.

Comment: @errata how do you know what needs to change? I do not suppose that the fields marked as "THIS SHOULD BE UPDATED" were chosen randomly.

Comment: @lesingerouge I need to update only fields with key names `"value"` or `"readonly"`.

Comment: @errata and all fields that need to be updated have the example content phrase or are they empty?

Comment: @lesingerouge 'value' fields would be empty, 'readonly' would be either empty or 'false' initally and I would have to change them to 'true'.

Comment: @errata ok, give me ten minutes. There might be an old script of mine you could use.

Comment: @Roberto Sure thing! No hurries ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's this small script that I had written a couple years ago - I used it to find entries in some very long and unnerving JSONs.  Admittedly it's not beautiful, but it might help in your case, perhaps?
You can find the script on Bitbucket, [here](https://bitbucket.org/bioruffo/recursivesearch) (and [here](https://bitbucket.org/bioruffo/recursivesearch/src/62b73e984866d094bb31c990b5b696fd20f95341?at=default) is the code).
Unfortunately it's not documented; at the time I wasn't really believing other people would use it, I guess.
Anyways, if you'd like to try it, save the script in your working directory and then use something like this:

```
from RecursiveSearch import Retriever

def alter_data(json_data, key, original, newval):
    '''
    Alter *all* values of said keys
    '''
    retr = Retriever(json_data)
    for item_no, item in enumerate(retr.__track__(key)): # i.e. all 'value'
        # Pick parent objects with a last element False in the __track__() result,
        # indicating that `key` is either a dict key or a set element
        if not item[-1]: 
            parent = retr.get_parent(key, item_no)
            try:
                if parent[key] == original:
                    parent[key] = newval
            except TypeError:
                # It's a set, this is not the key you're looking for
                pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    alter_data(notification, key='value', 
               original = '********** THIS SHOULD BE UPDATED **********',
               newval = '*UPDATED*')
```

Unfortunately as I said the script isn't well documented, so if you want to try it and need more info, I'll be glad to provide it.

Comment: PS: you can also use the `parent` element to verify further that the value needs to be updated, i.e. update only if it also contains a `label` key, or other checks.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if I understood correctly, but this will dynamically find all keys "value" and "readonly" and print out the paths to address the fields.

```
def findem(data, trail):
    if isinstance(data, dict):
        for k in data.keys():
            if k in ('value', 'readonly'):
                print("{}['{}']".format(trail, k))
            else:
                findem(data[k], "{}['{}']".format(trail, k))
    elif isinstance(data, list):
        for k in data:
            findem(k, '{}[{}]'.format(trail, data.index(k)))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    findem(notification, 'notification')

notification['children'][2]['children'][0]['children'][0]['readonly']
notification['children'][2]['children'][0]['children'][0]['value']
notification['children'][2]['children'][0]['children'][1]['readonly']
notification['children'][2]['children'][0]['children'][1]['value']
notification['children'][2]['children'][1]['children'][0]['readonly']
notification['children'][2]['children'][1]['children'][0]['options'][0]['value']
notification['children'][2]['children'][1]['children'][0]['options'][1]['value']
notification['children'][2]['children'][1]['children'][0]['options'][2]['value']
notification['children'][3]['children'][0]['children'][0]['value']
notification['children'][3]['children'][0]['children'][1]['value']
notification['children'][3]['children'][0]['children'][2]['value']
```

Answer (score 1):

Add another list to the JSON object. Each item in that list would be a list of keys that lead to the values to be changed. An example for one such list is: `['children', 2, 'children', 'children', 0, 'value']`.
Then, to access the value you could use a loop:

```
def change(json, path, newVal):
    cur = json
    for key in path[:-1]:
        cur = cur[key]
    cur[path[-1]] = newVal

path = notification['paths'][0]
#path, for example, could be ['children', 2, 'children', 'children', 0, 'value']
newVal = 'what ever you want'
change(notification, path, newVal)
```

Comment: This looks interesting. I'll try to play around with it a bit and will report back after success or failure :)

Comment: please report back @errata :)